# mouse lags in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

My old USB corded mouse lags/(pauses and skips) in windows 7 and don't have a clue what to do! I have seen many posts on the net from people having the same issue, yet no solution. stack exchange is my last hope. The lagging has nothing to do with cpu or graphics card, I have the same issue with my both computer at work and at home but same mouse. The lagging has nothing to do with running any program either. It just lags when I move it around, pauses for a sec and then skips and then continues moving!

Comment: Is the mouse clean (either in the optical sensor or the ball rollers)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the USB cable has become lose where it attaches to the mouse. I had similar experiences with previous mice. I would suggest you to get a new mouse. But you can still fix yours by rewiring. Just for confirmation you can watch and try this troubleshooting video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ml9_cvGZur4

Here's the general instructions: http://www.howany.com/how-to-fix-mouse/
Here's an example where they use the Apple Mighty Mouse: http://www.instructables.com/id/Fix-a-bad-cable-on-your-Mighty-Mouse/

Most mice have a very similar wiring as far as I remember, so it shouldn't be that different for fixing the cable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have pets?  One of the most common problems I have seen with an optical mouse in a house with pets is that hair gets in the hole where the light is.  Turn the mouse over and look in the hole under good light.  Even a single hair can cause the sensor to work improperly.